# SD card files get destroyed by my PC

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, sd-card, mobile-phone

My PC (At work) is an HP 6305 mini-case system (I bought it as a second hand several months ago) that I have installed Windows7 Ultimate 64bit on it.

When I connect an SD card to its USB port, it shows file names with gibberish characters, and when i opened the folder again the files were eliminated (Apparently).

It happened two times so far; first when i connected a Samsung mobile phone via USB several weeks ago, then today when I connected an SD flash memory card via an SD card adapter.

It is horrible!
What can be the reason of this horrible behavior and how to fix it?

I have no such problem with ordinary Flash disks. Seems that only SD cards or maybe flash memories belonging to smart phones are affected.

Can it be a file system incompatibility problem?

Comment: Win7 shouldn't have such compatibility problems (unless the SD cards are exFAT formated?). A faulty USB port is more likely.

Comment: How are you connecting the SD cards, using an internal reader or the same USB reader? Does it work on other computers? Maybe the reader is bad/flakey, or the card's are just bad, or that pc's usb is bad

Comment: @Xen2050 seems the problem is on PC side because I used two different SD cards connected via different ways but with the same result.

Comment: Seems like the SD card was not "ejected" *before* it was put in the office PC, i.e. the file system was not properly closed.

Answer (score -1):

Open My computer, go to Tool - Folder Options

Select View Tab
Select the View Hidden files and folders box
Uncheck the "Hide Protected Operating system files"

Open your SD card and see if there is any folder you can see without any name.

If there is any such folder, your files must be inside the folder.
This usually happens because of the virus in the computer.

Solution to get the files back to normal:-
The folders & files can be reverted to normal by using Command Prompt in safe mode.

Comment: But it does it only to SD cards and not ordinary flash disks. I think SD cards and flash disks seem akin to PC/Windows or any viruses.

Comment: Normally such virus effects any external storage device connected to the computer.
But, did you find your files?

Comment: That SD card wasn't mine and I am at home now. I should test that with my own SD card tomorrow at work.

Comment: No Problem, drop your test response once you check it.